# Primefaces dialog no se abren tras migrar a java 1.8

Tags: java, jsf, java-8, primefaces, weblogic

He migrado un proyecto de java 1.6 a 1.8 y de Weblogic 10.3.6 a 12c, tras esto no me abren los dialog (modales) de Primefaces. La versión de Primefaces que utilizo es la 6.1. ¿Por qué puede pasar esto? ¿Es incompatible con alguna de esas versiones?

Asi llamo a abrir modal desde la vista:

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" ... />
```

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error en los logs o en la consola del navegador? Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour], es complicado ayudarte sin conocer todo el contexto

Comment: @PabloLozano no aparece ningún error, ni en consola ni en el f12.. Son los modales genéricos de primefaces "p:dialog" con la version anterior de java 1.6 funcionaba pero al migrar a 1.8 ya no se abren.